# Plotly - yaxis min and max value not showing

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I'm using plotly to create some plots. I haven't modified the yaxis range, but I don't like how the chart is displaying the y axis. In the image attached the chart y axis numbers go from 25 to 40, but I have data that is slightly above 40 and below 25. Is there an option to force the y axis to always be higher than the min and max value that I have? Also, is it possible to have the y axis starting at the edges? (Highlighted in purple)

Thank you for your time!

[image]

Edit:
As asked in the comments, I've added my code below:

```
fig= go.Figure()

fig.update_layout(
        template="simple_white",
        font=_a_font,
        height=400,
        legend=dict(
            orientation="h",
            yanchor="bottom",
            y=1.02,
            xanchor="left",
            x=0,
            font=dict(size=16),
            itemclick=False,
            itemdoubleclick=False,
        ),
    )

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(range=x_range, mirror=True, tickmode='linear', tick0=0,dtick=1))
        
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True,mirror=True)
   
            
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=sub_x_data,
                         y=y, 
                         mode="lines+markers", 
                         name=legend_name,
                         line=dict(color=get_driver_color(legend_name)),
                                         textposition="bottom center",
                                         text = h_data,
                                         hoverinfo="text"))
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to see your code, as this chart doesn't look like a default style chart in Plotly.

That being said, you should be able to set the range manually, and specify the location of the first tick: `fig.update_yaxes(range=[20, 45], tick0=0)`

Comment: I'm using a template from plotly. It's called: "simple_white". I'm not using any custom chart.

Comment: Hey Derek. Sorry, but your answer didn't help me. I don't want to use the range function, because I don't always know what are the min and max values. I want plotly to automatically put the min and max values in the edges.

Comment: My misunderstanding– could you do something like `fig.update_yaxes(range=[min(data), max(data)], tick0=0)` where data is the variable where you're storing your data?

Comment: No worries at all! And thank you for taking the time to help me :D
I tried your suggestion: `fig.update_yaxes(range=[min(data), max(data)], tick0=0)`, but I end up having the same result. I think this is the behavior of plotly and I can't change it. See here the chart using your suggestion: https://ibb.co/S50LFb1

Comment: Hmm you may be right about the default behavior for Plotly– I'll see if I can figure anything out .